# Call disconnect if app is terminated

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, twilio-api

I use Twilio API to create video between two users. It works good if one of the users clicks on "Disconnect". But when user terminates his app, the picture "freezes". How can I disconnect user if he terminates his app (turns off internet connection, ...) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I would implement the [`TVIRoomDelegate` methods `didDisconnectWithError` and `participantDidDisconnect`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/video/releases/1.0.0-beta15/docs/Protocols/TVIRoomDelegate.html) so that you can clear up video connections when a disconnection is detected.